# Modulo operator in decryption

Tags: math, encryption, modulo, algebra

I'm creating an encryptor/decryptor for ascii strings where I take the ascii value of a char, add 1 to it, then mod it by the highest ascii value so that I get a valid ascii char out.
The problem is the decryption.

Let's say that (a + b) % c = d
I know b, c, and d's values.
How do I get the a variables value out from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the inverse formula

```
a = (b - d) mod c
```

or in practice

```
a = (b - d + c) % c.
```

The term `+ c` needs to be added as a safeguard because the `%` operator does not implement a true modulo in the negatives.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the ROT1 substitution cipher. Subtract 1, and if less than lowest value (0 I assume, given how you're describing it), then add the highest value.

Using terms like "mod," while accurate, make this seem more complicated than it is. It's just addition on a ring. When you go past the last letter, you come back to the first letter and vice-versa. Once you put your head around how the math works, the equations should pop out. Basically, you just add or subtract as normal (add to encrypt, subtract to decrypt in this case), and at the end, `mod` "normalizes" you back onto the ring of legal values.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `c` is 2, `d` is 0 and `b` is 4.

Now we know that `a` **must** be 2... Or 4 actually.. or 6... Or any other even number.

You can't solve this problem, there are infinite solutions.

Comment: `c` can't be 2 in this cipher if `b` is 4. `c` is the largest value in the system. ("mod it by the highest ascii value")

Comment: @RobNapier I'm focusing directly on the equation that is presented since that is what the question was asked about. I'm not familiar with the cipher, it clearly changes the context.  Thanks for the info, I think the OP can still learn from my answer however.